# powershell to iterate files in azure repo

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

how can I loop in a folder in azure devops using powershell and run all the sql statements.

I have folder structure like this. Azure Repo> SQL folder... DDL folder ...DML folder

```
SQL 
   DDL
    SQLDDL1
    SQLDDL2
    SQLDDL3
  DML
    SQLDML1
    SQLDML2
    SQLDML3
```

I am able to run this  fetch.ps1.

```
$params = @{

  'Database' = 'db-01'
  'ServerInstance' =  'sql-db1-database.windows.net'
  'Username' = 'User'
  'Password' = 'test'
  'OutputSqlErrors' = $true
  'Query' = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[con]'
  }

  Invoke-Sqlcmd  @params
```

Now i want the content of Query replace by a file in azure repo.

how can I get handle of folder which is placed in azure repos and run the sql scripts (SQL>DDL and SQL>DML)

i got into this but not able to find out $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

```
Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ [source alias]\drop | 
ForEach-Object{
 $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
 Write-Host $content
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case by using script in a default variable need to use below format.

To use a default variable in your script, you must first replace the `.` in the default variable names with `_`. For example, to print the value of `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`
in a PowerShell script, you would use `$env: System_DefaultWorkingDirectory`.

```
$env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory
```

Refer for more  [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#using-default-variables)